# SpringBoot erro ao retornar JSON

Tags: java, spring-boot

Estou usando Spring Boot na minha API. O Spring tem a capacidade de converter JavaBeans automaticamente em JSONs quando se retorna um objeto.

Todavia, com esse código (na minha camada MODEL) estou tendo uma ClassCastException.

```
public InfosUserLogado listaUsuarioLogado(TokenApp tokenApp) {
    ResponseEntity<InfosUserLogado> responseEntity = requester.doRequest(tokenApp, Constants.USER_AUTHENTICATED_URL, HttpMethod.GET, null);
    return responseEntity.getBody();
}
```

> java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to me.package.toolsapi.model.users.pojo.InfosUserLogado

Comment: Verifique se seu método ou controladora possui a anotação `@ResponseBody`

Comment: Possui a anotação, sim.